# Modifying String while being displayed in script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to figure out how to write a bash script that does something like this at about 0:55 where the characters are constantly changing between - / \ |
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwK2NReSRFU

How would I do something like this but have the first echo command deleted before doing the second?

```
echo "hello"
sleep 1
echo "Hello"
sleep 1
echo "hEllo"
slep 1
echo "heLlo"
```

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store and restore the cursor position and clear the current line. This done using [*ANSI terminal escape sequences*](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm):

```
echo -en "\033[s" # Save cursor position
while true ; do 
    echo -n "hello"
    sleep 1
    echo -en "\033[1K" # Clear current line
    echo -en "\033[u" # Restore cursor position
    echo -n "Hello"
    sleep 1
    echo -en "\033[1K"
    echo -en "\033[u"
    echo -n "hEllo"
    sleep 1
    echo -en "\033[1K"
    echo -en "\033[u"
    echo -n "heLlo"
    sleep 1
    echo -en "\033[1K"
    echo -en "\033[u"
    echo -n "helLo"
    sleep 1
    echo -en "\033[1K"
    echo -en "\033[u"
    echo -n "hellO"
    sleep 1
    echo -en "\033[1K"
    echo -en "\033[u"
done
```